# Draw a line that goes outside the image

Tags: python

I need to draw a line that start from a coordinate in the image and if it goes outside the image it will keep drawing starting from the opposite side like the videogame "Snake".
I don't know how to perform this with Python without using libraries.

Example:
after opening an image
I create a `for` loop taking the commands where to go

```
if x==(commands value)
x+=1
image[y][x] == (100,100,100)
```

(100,100,100) is the color

but I don't know how to tell Python when the line goes out of range to go back to the opposite side. For example if the picture is wide 100 pixel and i start from position of x 90 after 10 pixel it will be at the edge of the picture and if it keeps the for loop it will return me 'out of index', I want to give my function the option to go back to position x 0 when it arrives at position of x 101.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

`image[y % image_height ][x % image_width] = (100, 100, 100)`

Modulo operator : https://realpython.com/python-modulo-operator/

Comment: (100,100,100) is the color, but how can I give the input to keep drawing on the opposite side? like the snake videogame that when the snake go to the edge of the image it keeps moving appearing on the opposite side

Comment: using the modulo as I've written